# Netlogo: Return the Minimum of calculated values

Tags: netlogo

I am getting an **"expected a constant" error** when I try to return the minimum value between two calculated values.

In my model, patches own ag, glc, and pH. According to the values of these, each patch should calculate the **NP-ag-glc-effect** and **NP-ag-pH-effect**, and use which ever of these two calculated value is smaller for further calculation.

In the code below, Netlogo is giving an error at the min [NP-ag-glc-effect NP-ag-pH-effect]. Any helping in solving this problem is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
J.J.

```
to calc-ag     
  let NP-ag-baseline random-normal .85 .17            

  set ag (ag + (NP-ag-baseline * (min [NP-ag-glc-effect NP-ag-pH-effect]))        
end

to-report NP-ag-glc-effect
   ifelse glc < .5 [ report .5 ]                                     
                   [ report ((.11 * glc) + .44) ]                   
  end

  to-report NP-ag-pH-effect
    ifelse pH > 6.6 [report (1.52 * pH) - 9.9]                       
                    [report ((.28 * pH) - 1.71)]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` [expects a list](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min) to choose from:

```
set ag (ag + (NP-ag-baseline * (min (list NP-ag-glc-effect NP-ag-pH-effect))))
```

(also note a missing closing parenthesis in your code snippet)